# How to hook Linux syscall(s) on a kernel compiled with CET

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am currently following along with the book **The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide**. Chapter 19 focuses on syscalls. The chapter touches briefly on Control Flow Enforcement Technology but does not delve deeper into this. With recent kernels introducing Indirect Branch Tracking (IBT) and the shadow stack I'm confused as to how this code could be adapted to still work on the more recent kernels. For reference, I am on kernel 6.5.8-arch-1-1 with IBT enabled. Any usage of the kprobe method to hook these syscalls crashes with a `traps: Missing ENDBR` error message. Is there any way to still make this example code work?

```
/*
 * syscall.c
 *
 * System call "stealing" sample.
 *
 * Disables page protection at a processor level by changing the 16th bit
 * in the cr0 register (could be Intel specific).
 *
 * Based on example by Peter Jay Salzman and
 * https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139406
 */

#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h> /* which will have params */
#include <linux/unistd.h> /* The list of system calls */
#include <linux/cred.h> /* For current_uid() */
#include <linux/uidgid.h> /* For __kuid_val() */
#include <linux/version.h>

/* For the current (process) structure, we need this to know who the
 * current user is.
 */
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

/* The way we access "sys_call_table" varies as kernel internal changes.
 * - Prior to v5.4 : manual symbol lookup
 * - v5.5 to v5.6  : use kallsyms_lookup_name()
 * - v5.7+         : Kprobes or specific kernel module parameter
 */

/* The in-kernel calls to the ksys_close() syscall were removed in Linux v5.11+.
 */
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE < KERNEL_VERSION(5, 7, 0))

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE <= KERNEL_VERSION(5, 4, 0)
#define HAVE_KSYS_CLOSE 1
#include <linux/syscalls.h> /* For ksys_close() */
#else
#include <linux/kallsyms.h> /* For kallsyms_lookup_name */
#endif

#else

#if defined(CONFIG_KPROBES)
#define HAVE_KPROBES 1
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#else
#define HAVE_PARAM 1
#include <linux/kallsyms.h> /* For sprint_symbol */
/* The address of the sys_call_table, which can be obtained with looking up
 * "/boot/System.map" or "/proc/kallsyms". When the kernel version is v5.7+,
 * without CONFIG_KPROBES, you can input the parameter or the module will look
 * up all the memory.
 */
static unsigned long sym = 0;
module_param(sym, ulong, 0644);
#endif /* CONFIG_KPROBES */

#endif /* Version < v5.7 */

static unsigned long **sys_call_table;

/* UID we want to spy on - will be filled from the command line. */
static uid_t uid = -1;
module_param(uid, int, 0644);

/* A pointer to the original system call. The reason we keep this, rather
 * than call the original function (sys_openat), is because somebody else
 * might have replaced the system call before us. Note that this is not
 * 100% safe, because if another module replaced sys_openat before us,
 * then when we are inserted, we will call the function in that module -
 * and it might be removed before we are.
 *
 * Another reason for this is that we can not get sys_openat.
 * It is a static variable, so it is not exported.
 */
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER
static asmlinkage long (*original_call)(const struct pt_regs *);
#else
static asmlinkage long (*original_call)(int, const char __user *, int, umode_t);
#endif

/* The function we will replace sys_openat (the function called when you
 * call the open system call) with. To find the exact prototype, with
 * the number and type of arguments, we find the original function first
 * (it is at fs/open.c).
 *
 * In theory, this means that we are tied to the current version of the
 * kernel. In practice, the system calls almost never change (it would
 * wreck havoc and require programs to be recompiled, since the system
 * calls are the interface between the kernel and the processes).
 */
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER
static asmlinkage long our_sys_openat(const struct pt_regs *regs)
#else
static asmlinkage long our_sys_openat(int dfd, const char __user *filename,
                                      int flags, umode_t mode)
#endif
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch;

    if (__kuid_val(current_uid()) != uid)
        goto orig_call;

    /* Report the file, if relevant */
    pr_info("Opened file by %d: ", uid);
    do {
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER
        get_user(ch, (char __user *)regs->si + i);
#else
        get_user(ch, (char __user *)filename + i);
#endif
        i++;
        pr_info("%c", ch);
    } while (ch != 0);
    pr_info("\n");

orig_call:
    /* Call the original sys_openat - otherwise, we lose the ability to
     * open files.
     */
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER
    return original_call(regs);
#else
    return original_call(dfd, filename, flags, mode);
#endif
}

static unsigned long **acquire_sys_call_table(void)
{
#ifdef HAVE_KSYS_CLOSE
    unsigned long int offset = PAGE_OFFSET;
    unsigned long **sct;

    while (offset < ULLONG_MAX) {
        sct = (unsigned long **)offset;

        if (sct[__NR_close] == (unsigned long *)ksys_close)
            return sct;

        offset += sizeof(void *);
    }

    return NULL;
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_PARAM
    const char sct_name[15] = "sys_call_table";
    char symbol[40] = { 0 };

    if (sym == 0) {
        pr_alert("For Linux v5.7+, Kprobes is the preferable way to get "
                 "symbol.\n");
        pr_info("If Kprobes is absent, you have to specify the address of "
                "sys_call_table symbol\n");
        pr_info("by /boot/System.map or /proc/kallsyms, which contains all the "
                "symbol addresses, into sym parameter.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    sprint_symbol(symbol, sym);
    if (!strncmp(sct_name, symbol, sizeof(sct_name) - 1))
        return (unsigned long **)sym;

    return NULL;
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_KPROBES
    unsigned long (*kallsyms_lookup_name)(const char *name);
    struct kprobe kp = {
        .symbol_name = "kallsyms_lookup_name",
    };

    if (register_kprobe(&kp) < 0)
        return NULL;
    kallsyms_lookup_name = (unsigned long (*)(const char *name))kp.addr;
    unregister_kprobe(&kp);
#endif

    return (unsigned long **)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
}

#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(5, 3, 0)
static inline void __write_cr0(unsigned long cr0)
{
    asm volatile("mov %0,%%cr0" : "+r"(cr0) : : "memory");
}
#else
#define __write_cr0 write_cr0
#endif

static void enable_write_protection(void)
{
    unsigned long cr0 = read_cr0();
    set_bit(16, &cr0);
    __write_cr0(cr0);
}

static void disable_write_protection(void)
{
    unsigned long cr0 = read_cr0();
    clear_bit(16, &cr0);
    __write_cr0(cr0);
}

static int __init syscall_start(void)
{
    if (!(sys_call_table = acquire_sys_call_table()))
        return -1;

    disable_write_protection();

    /* keep track of the original open function */
    original_call = (void *)sys_call_table[__NR_openat];

    /* use our openat function instead */
    sys_call_table[__NR_openat] = (unsigned long *)our_sys_openat;

    enable_write_protection();

    pr_info("Spying on UID:%d\n", uid);

    return 0;
}

static void __exit syscall_end(void)
{
    if (!sys_call_table)
        return;

    /* Return the system call back to normal */
    if (sys_call_table[__NR_openat] != (unsigned long *)our_sys_openat) {
        pr_alert("Somebody else also played with the ");
        pr_alert("open system call\n");
        pr_alert("The system may be left in ");
        pr_alert("an unstable state.\n");
    }

    disable_write_protection();
    sys_call_table[__NR_openat] = (unsigned long *)original_call;
    enable_write_protection();

    msleep(2000);
}

module_init(syscall_start);
module_exit(syscall_end);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```